# How to pass authorization headers to WCF service in javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, wcf-security

This is the request that I am sending via javascript on a click of a button.

```
    _crmProxy = "http://xxxxxxx:12355/dev_test/Service1.svc";
    var name = "yz\\c.crm";
    var pwd = "321@";
    var text = "Parshu";
    var response = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(name + ':' + pwd),
            'Content-Type' :'application/json'
        },
        data: '{"userName": "' + text + '" }',
        url: _crmProxy + "/WelcomeUser",
        success: function (result) {
            response = result.WelcomeUserResult;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("err");
        }
    });
```

but I am getting 401 Unauthorized OPTIONS error and couldn't go ahead. Can you please tell me where am I going wrong.

Thank you.

Prashant

Comment: You tagged this question with the Basic tag, but you seem not to use the Basic programming language?

Comment: Can anyone please help me in getting this Basic authentication work? I think I am getting wrong in some syntaxes or something. Please guide me.